# Nginx regex alias

Tags: nginx

Hi I'm trying to serve /myproject/build/article/1/index.html on 127.0.0.1:8080/article/1/foo or 127.0.0.1:8080/article/1 in nginx. 'foo' (slug) in the url should be optional.

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    location ~ ^/article/(?<id>\d+)/(?<slug>.*)?{
        alias /myproject/build/article/$id/index.html;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use root directive

```
    server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    location ~ ^/article/(\d+)/foo/(.*){
        alias /myproject/build/article/\1/index.html;
    }
}
```

OR

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
location ~ ^/article/(\d+)/foo/(.*){
    alias /myproject/build/article/\1/index.html;
}
```

}

It is explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)!